# AWS EC2 Access Denied S3 Cross Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, roles

I have two aws accounts A and B.

In the account A, I have an EC2 running inside a vpc in a private subnet that has a NAT on.
This EC2 has the following role:

AWS Account A - EC2 Role Trusted entities:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
]
```

}

AWS Account A - EC2 Role Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-B-NUMBER:role/aws-access-s3"
        }
    ]
}
```

In the account B, I created an aws account role passing the aws account A number.

AWS Account B - Role aws-access-s3 Trusted entities:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-A-NUMBER:root"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

AWS Account B - Role aws-access-s3 Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "s3-object-lambda:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

These are my setup and when I try to run the command to list the account B buccket inside the ec2 in Account A I'm getting the error:

```
aws s3 ls bucket-name-account-b
```

Returns:

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied
```

I don't know what I'm missing, I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Did you actually assume the role in account B?

Comment: @luk2302, I'm not sure if the configs are correct because it's the first time i'm testing this cross account role, but what I need is to access the account b bucket from the account a ec2.

Comment: This seems to be correct. Your aws credentials might be the issue. Try `aws sts assume-role --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::accountb:role/yourrole" --role-session-name "test"` do you get access and secret access keys plus token?

Comment: @Riz, I tested this command and it worked, it returns key, secret and session token, but still not able to list the data in the bucket of the account b.

Comment: You need to export these keys. export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=RoleAccessKeyID
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=RoleSecretKey
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=RoleSessionToken       after these try your command

Comment: @Riz, after exporting the credentials I was able to list the bucket. Is this how it is supposed to work or this export step should've happened automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a profile to make this process automatic.
You can add the following to your `.aws/config` file

```
[profile mys3profile]
region = $region
output = json
```

and the following to your `.aws/credentials` file.

```
[mys3profile]   
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::accountb:role/yourrole
credential_source = Ec2InstanceMetadata
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's gonna work. Do you think I can also try the same for an application in emr serverless ?

Comment: No problem :-) I am not very familiar with emr. I would suggest you to open another ticket here. Someone will surely help you out.